# ClamScan skip files During the scan

Tags: linux, virus, anti-virus, inotify, clamav

We have configured ClamAV to automatically scan files in a monitored directory using inotifywait.

```
# Start the monitoring tool and log the scan results
nohup inotifywait -m -r -e create "$MONITOR_DIR" --format '%w%f' |

        # Scan the file with ClamAV
        
        SCAN_RESULT=$(sudo clamdscan --remove --fdpass --multiscan -v "$FILE" 2>&1)


        # Log the result of the scan
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
          echo "$(date) - ClamAV: $FILE - OK" >> $CLAMAV_LOG
        else
          echo "$(date) - ClamAV: $FILE - INFECTED" >> $CLAMAV_LOG
          INFECTED_FILES=$((INFECTED_FILES+1))

          # Delete the infected file
          rm "$FILE"
```

The ClamAV daemon has been given full access to the monitoring directory and its logs. However, during our testing, we have observed that ClamAV sometimes skips files during the scan. For example, when scanning 20,000 files, only 14,000 files may actually be scanned.